# Javascript filter don't work on Google Script Apps function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I'm trying to use a filter on a HTML page.
But something is going wrong when turning the spreadsheet data into a slice: `userCodeAppPanel:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at Pesquisa (userCodeAppPanel:53) at HTMLButtonElement.Teste (userCodeAppPanel:94)`

I got inspired by this video lesson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CSPpsBGlQ0&t=123s

I suspect it is something with the `CarregaDados()` function initialization.

There is a field where I choose the type of equipment and an input to search for the serial number
[image]

I am using a table inside a sweetAlert2 to show the spreadsheet data.
but no data in the  tag appears.

[image]

**The Code:**
**HTML**

```js
<script>
  var dado;
  
  function CarregaDados() {
    var Tipo_pesquisa = document.getElementById("Tipop").value;
    switch (Tipo_pesquisa) {
      case 'Transmissor':
        var flag = 'Transmissores';
        break;
      case 'Central':
        var flag = 'Centrais';
        break;
      case 'Repetidor':
        var flag = 'Repetidores';
        break;
      case 'Gateway':
        var flag = 'Gateways';
        break;
      case 'Mobile':
        var flag = 'Mobiles';
        break;
    };
  
  
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(retorna_dado) {
      dado = retorna_dado.slice();
    }).PesquisaDado(flag);
  }
  
  function Pesquisa() {
  
  
    Swal.fire({
      title: '<h1 class="hlinha">Histórico do Equipamento: </h1>',
      width: 1000,
      html: '<center><table class="Ptable" style="width:100%"><thead><tr class="tr"><th scope="col">' +
        '<strong>Entada</strong></th><th scope="row"><strong>Modelo</strong></th>' +
        '<th scope="row"><strong>SN ou MAC</strong></th><th scope="row"><strong>Ocorrência</strong></th>' +
        '<th scope= "row"><strong>Status</strong></th><th scope="row"><strong>Data</strong></th><th scope="row">' +
        '<strong>Observações</strong></th><th scope="row"><strong>Funcionário</strong></th></tr><tr class="tr"></thead>' +
        '<tbody id="ResultadoPesquisa"></tbody></table></center><template id="Template">' +
        '<tr><th scope="row"></th><td class="Modelo"></td><td class="Sn"></td><td class="ocorrencia"></td><td class="status"></td>' +
        '<td class="data"></td><td class="obs"></td><td class="funcionario"></td></tr></template>',
      showCloseButton: true,
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  
  
    var SN = document.getElementById("SN_Pesquisa").value.toString().toLowerCase();
    var resultadoArr = dado.filter(function(r) {
      return r[2].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(SN) !== -1;
    });
  
    var caixa = document.getElementById("ResultadoPesquisa");
    var template2 = document.getElementById("Template");
    var template = template2.content;
    resultadoArr.forEach(function(r) {
      var linha = template.cloneNode(true);
  
      var Entrada_C = linha.querySelector(".Entrada");
      var Modelo_C = linha.querySelector(".Modelo");
      var Sn_C = linha.querySelector(".Sn");
      var ocorrencia_C = linha.querySelector(".ocorrencia");
      var status_C = linha.querySelector(".status");
      var data_C = linha.querySelector(".data");
      var obs_C = linha.querySelector(".obs");
      var funcionario_C = linha.querySelector(".funcionario");
  
      Entrada_C.textContent = r[0];
      Modelo_C.textContent = r[1];
      Sn_C.textContent = r[2];
      ocorrencia_C.textContent = r[3];
      status_C.textContent = r[4];
      data_C.textContent = r[5];
      obs_C.textContent = r[6];
      funcionario_C.textContent = r[7];
  
  
      caixa.appendChild(linha);
  
    });
  
  }
  
  function Teste(e) {
    if (e.target.matches("#ResultadoPesquisa")) {
      Pesquisa();
    } else {
      CarregaDados();
      Pesquisa();
    };
  }
  
  document.getElementById("Pesquisa").addEventListener("click", Teste);
</script>
```

**gs**

```js
function PesquisaDado(Tipo) {  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName(Tipo);

  return ws.getRange(9,3,ws.getLastRow()-9,8).getValues();  
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to do a bit of debugging. Can you reduce the problem (and code) down to only the necessary parts? Throw in some `console.log`s where you can to get a better sense of where and when `dado` is being set, and to what value.

Comment: Do you ever call `CarregaDados`?  If that doesn't run, then `PesquisaDado` doesn't run, and `dado` remains undefined.  Make sure `CarregaDados` is actually being run.  If you need a default array to get past the error, update `var dado;` to `var dado = [];`